# Waiting for a set variable in another Spring component

Tags: java, spring

I have a component A that asynchronously (@Async interface is used) runs the `foo()` method in component B. However, it may happen that the data in component B is not initialized yet and then `foo()` does not work correctly. Component A needs to wait for the data in component B to be initialized.

Is there any high-level solution in Spring (I don't want to play directly with threads) that will try to wait for some time to see if component B initializes and if it initializes earlier, can the `foo()` method run as well? `Thread.sleep()` works, but it always waits the whole time, which I don't need.

Comment: rule of thumb: never ever try to interact with other beans or infrastructure when spring is constructing application context, either wait for `ContextRefreshedEvent` or take advantage of `org.springframework.context.Lifecycle`